# Pages on Area 51 aren't rendered correctly when the browser's window is tighter than the body

Tags: bug, design, area-51, top-bar, footer

There are some weirdnesses in how pages on Area 51 are rendered when the browser's window is tighter than the body:

[image: screenshot]

Namely the `div` `.wrapper` is resized according to the window's width, and the `div` `.topbar` and `.footer` get resized along with it, in `.topbar`'s case exposing what's behind it.